# Session store Json on javascript and use it on server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

Is it possible to store JSON object in session from Javascript/Jquery.
and that session key value used on Server side.

Comment: Sessions are stored in Server, not in the client side

Comment: I do not exactly understand the question. Do you want to store JS-generated data in session, ie. pass it to backend as JSON?

Comment: You need to make an AJAX request to server with your JSON data and from there you can process it and/or add it to Session.

Comment: ... or use cookies if it's smaller than 4kb

Comment: I wanted to store collection of string, it can be array or json in single key of session. and access that session value on server side

Answer (score 1):

you can store it as a cookie or send it back to the server using ajax or encode it into the url and pass it to the server to be stored.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass data directly from localStorage / sessionStorage to backend, but what you can do is, saving JSON string in a cookie and then accessing it from backend.

Answer (score 0):

> Can it possible to store JSON object in sessin from Javascript/Jquery

No, at least not directly, but that is the same as any other piece of data you have on the client.

If you want to store something in a session, then you must send it to the server. You can do that by putting it in an HTTP request (e.g. via Ajax).

You then have a string on the server which you can store using your normal session API.

> and use it on server side

Once it is in the session, you can use it freely on the server. You don't even need to put it in the session (although, if you don't, it will be lost before the next request).

Answer (score 0):

can store it on the session by sending the json object text to the server using AJAX. On the server end there are JSON libraries to recreate the object, then use its properties on the server side. Sending via AJAX has the advantage of not needing to refresh the page.

Like T J Crowder nooted you could use a cookie to.